# How to override styles.css with the component.css (Angular)

Tags: css, angular

I have a generic `.modal-content` set in **styles.css**. This applies to every modal panel in the application.
I would like to override its  width in the **component.css**. This component has also a modal panel, and even if I put the following into the **component.css**, the modal will retain its global width.

```
.modal-content{
  border-radius: 0;
  border:none;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Even if I use `!important` it does not have any effect.

What can I do to override the global css value?

**EDIT**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-data',
  templateUrl: './base-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base-data.component.css']
})
export class BaseDataComponent implements OnInit {
```

Comment: Could you also post your component html and ts? What view encapsulation strategy are you using?

Comment: you can set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the component

Comment: Would advice that turning `ViewEncapsulation` off might cause more issues as well

Comment: @JoelJoseph it works. make it an answer. and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Sanyifejű  done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To override global style rule on the component style file, add this on your component.ts

`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

check out the official doc : https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: but this will leak the component.css to the rest of the application :(

Comment: I get the desired effect without leaking to other components using encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom